# HttpClient.get with headers

Tags: angular, http-headers

I'm trying to get a file with HttpClient.get using the following code. 
The file is XML so I added content-type to the headers.

I printed the Headers variable and got:

```
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: Array(1), headers: Map(0), lazyInit: HttpHeaders}
headers: Map(1) {"content-type" => Array(1)}
lazyInit: null
lazyUpdate: null
normalizedNames: Map(1) {"content-type" => "Content-Type"}
__proto__: Object
```

Can you please explain what is wrong in my headers ?

BTW: I tried without any headers and got the following error:

```
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse
```

Currently, chorme is launched with: --disable-web-security

```
  let  Headers = new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  console.log (Headers);
  this.http.get ('http://localhost:80/dwell.xml',{headers: Headers}).subscribe  (=> {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `responseType` to `text`:

```
this.http.get ('http://localhost:80/dwell.xml' { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```